# Call SQLCLR procedure from another stored procedure and get 2 return values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I am using a stored procedure that calls another SQLCLR stored procedure. The SQLCLR procedure returns 2 values.

How to get 2 return values from SQLCLR procedure to the T-SQL stored procedure?

I know normally from C# getting the return value using output parameter. But confusing how to get and hold return value in normal stored procedure.

Comment: you mean to say i need to declare the two output paramater in DB Stored procedure. But i unable to declare the output parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLCLR Procedure:

```
public static void SendMailSP(out string Status, out string Message)
{
    Status = "hi:";
    Message = "Hello";
}
```

DB Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].udpTestOutParameter
{
DECLARE @Status varchar(100);
DECLARE @Message varchar(100);
EXECUTE dbo.SendMailSP @Status = @Status OUTPUT,@Message = @Message OUTPUT;
PRINT @Status
PRINT @Message
RETURN
}
```

I am getting the proper result. Thanks for post.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more 'correct' answer than this, but one easy way is to just put the two values into one and separate them with some character such as a comma, tab, pipe, etc.  So that way you are just returning one value and you can split it on the other end back into 2 values based on the delimeter.

Comment: Yeah I know that Method but i wanted to know whether I can get 2 return value from stored procedure executing another procedure. I got the answer. thanks for help